# Jquery, ajax won't alert some message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So I am doing a shopping cart site, using CodeIgniter on backend
Here is the catch, I loop the product list, with 'add to cart' button, inside a form tag.
So let's say, I have 5 products to display, there will be 5 form tag as:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $vid):?>

<form id='cart' method='post' action='<?php echo base_url();?>cart/add'>
<input type='hidden' id='vid' name='vid' value='<?php echo $vid['id'];?>'/>
<div class="video_box">
      <div class="video">
      <a href="#<?php echo $vid['id'];?>" name='modal'>
     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/<?php echo $vid['video_thumbnail'];?>" alt="<?php echo $vid['title'];?>" border="0" height='150' width='100' />
     </a>
      </div>                        
      <div class="video_checkbox">
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('nric')===FALSE ) {
     echo "Please Login to Rent/Purchase"; } else { ?>
     <input type='image' id='btn-add' src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/rent_btn.png" alt="Rent" border="0" />
     <?php } ?>
     </div>
</form>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

And my javascript/jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btn-add").click(function() {
   var action = $("#cart").attr('action');
   var form_data = {
       vid : $("#vid").val(),
       is_ajax  : 1
   };
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: action,
   data: form_data,
   success: function(response)
     {
       if(response == 'exists')
       { alert("This item is in your cart already! You can only add 1 same item once");
       }
       if(response == 'newses')
       {    alert("This item has been added succesfully!");
            document.location.reload(true);
       }
        if(response == 'new_added')
        {
            alert("This item has been added succesfully1!");
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
   }
  });
 return false;
   });
 });
    </script>
```

As my controller (in form action) localhost/site/cart/add:

```
public function add() {
    $vid=$_POST['vid'];

    if($this->session->userdata('shoppingCart')===FALSE)
    {   

        $shoppingCart = array (
                            $vid => 1
                        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('shoppingCart',$shoppingCart);
         echo 'newses';


    } else {    

        $tmp = $this->session->userdata('shoppingCart');
        if(array_key_exists($vid, $tmp)) {
            //only allow user to add qty:1 to the same product
            echo 'exists';

        } else {            
            $tmp[$vid]= 1;
            $this->session->set_userdata('shoppingCart',$tmp);
            echo 'new_added';


        }
    }

}
```

So the problem now, I can add the product to my shopping cart with no problem, all the stuff inside cart/add controller runs fine, the output is as expected.
But I need to alert the customer whether the product has been added or failed (as shown in my jquery code).
Problem is, the script will run fine only for the 1st  created.
Means, if there is 5 products, it will loop and create 5 form-tag right, only the 1st form-tag will run the script successfully (after the button is clicked). The 2nd-5th form will redirect to other blank page, echoing the result (e.g "newses", "new_added", "exists"), not alerting the user as stated in the script (but the shopping cart function works properly).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well since you are dealing with a loop item you have to use .closest and .find in Jquery and assign somekind of container div classes to it. I'll try to make a example for you in a bit

Comment: Never use same id more than one time in same page. change `id='btn-add'` to `class="btn-add"`. also jquery selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($products as $vid):?>

<form id='cart' method='post' action='<?php echo base_url();?>cart/add'>
<input type='hidden' class='vid' name='vid' value='<?php echo $vid['id'];?>'/>
<div class="video_box">
      <div class="video">
      <a href="#<?php echo $vid['id'];?>" name='modal'>
     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/<?php echo $vid['video_thumbnail'];?>" alt="<?php echo $vid['title'];?>" border="0" height='150' width='100' />
     </a>
      </div>                        
      <div class="video_checkbox">
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('nric')===FALSE ) {
     echo "Please Login to Rent/Purchase"; } else { ?>
     <input type='image' class='btn-add' src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/rent_btn.png" alt="Rent" border="0" />
     <?php } ?>
     </div>
</form>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-add").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $form = $this.parents('form');
        var action = $form.attr('action');
        var vid = $form.find('input.vid').val();
        var form_data = {
            vid : vid,
            is_ajax : 1
        };
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : action,
            data : form_data,
            success : function(response) {
                if (response == 'exists') {
                    alert("This item is in your cart already! You can only add 1 same item once");
                }
                if (response == 'newses') {
                    alert("This item has been added succesfully!");
                    document.location.reload(true);
                }
                if (response == 'new_added') {
                    alert("This item has been added succesfully1!");
                    document.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```